# Decrease file size of QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qbytearray

when i resize a QPixmap with scaledToHeight and then transform it to an QByteArray, the size of this ByteArray is exactly the size of ByteArray from the unscaled QPixmap. Is there a possibility to shrink QPixmap in pixel-size and file-size?

Best regards

Comment: Could you post some code? I've scaled `QPixmap`'s many a time and the resultant byte array is definitely smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof-of-concept that shows that what you are doing is certainly possible. Maybe you can see what you are doing different?

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QPixmap pixmap("/path/to/image.jpg");
  QByteArray bytes1;
  QBuffer buffer1(&bytes1);
  buffer1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  pixmap.save(&buffer1, "png");
  qDebug() << bytes1.size();

  pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(100);
  QByteArray bytes2;
  QBuffer buffer2(&bytes2);
  buffer2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  pixmap.save(&buffer2, "png");
  qDebug() << bytes2.size();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Two guesses:

- `scaledToHeight` returns a scaled *copy* of the original image. It does not scale the pixmap instance directly.
- If you are reusing the same `QByteArray`, you may have to truncate it before seeing the difference in size. That is, the *capacity* of the QByteArray may remain larger even through the *actual content* is much smaller.